# rename all files in a folder deleting duplicate string-parts

Tags: bash, rename, batch-jobs

I have a folder with lots of subfolders, that contain two times the same but slightly different:

```
Movie1 {Action}{Adventure}{Sci-Fi}{Thriller}{Science Fiction}/
Movie2 {Action}{Adventure}{Thriller}{Science Fiction}/
Movie3 {Action}{Adventure}{Thriller}{Sci-Fi}}/
Movie4 {Action}{Adventure}{Thriller}/
```

How do I unify these by deleting the part "{Science Fiction}" where "{Sci-Fi}" already exists, renaming the fodlers that dont't contain "{Sci-Fi}" but only "{Science Fiction}"?

I would go for a for loop:

```
for f in *; do
  if [ *"{Science Fiction}"* == "$f" ] && [ *"{Sci-Fi}"* == "$f" ]; then
    #delete the "{Science Fiction}" part
  else ...
  fi
done
```

But that doesn't seem very elegant. is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: That script seems nice and simple to me. Don't over-complicate things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed to remove the duplicates from string:

```
for f in *; do
  r=$(echo $f | sed -r "s/(.*)(\{Sci-Fi\}|\{Science Fiction\})(.*)(\{Sci-Fi\}|\{Science Fiction\})(.*)/\1\2\3\5/g");
  echo $r;
done
```

Replace `echo $f` with `mv "$f" "$r"` if you like the output.

The above `sed` line will take the first matching word and remove the second, if you want to always priorize `Sci-Fi` over `Science Fiction`, even when only `Science Fiction` exists, you can do it in two steps:

```
for f in *; do
  r=$(echo $f | sed "s/{Science Fiction}/{Sci-Fi}/");
  s=$(echo $r | sed -r "s/(.*)(\{Sci-Fi\})(.*)(\{Sci-Fi\})(.*)/\1\2\3\5/g");
  if [ "$f" != "$s" ]; then
    echo "moving " $f " to " $s
  fi
done
```

Comment: Great, this works! but I can now move it with `mv -v "$f" "$s"`

Comment: Oh, thanks for noting this, I didn't pay attention to the `echo` part =/